# Validate input fields in C programming

Tags: c

I want to validate my fields that I type, and display an error.
this is my code in C:

```
struct student
{
    char name[15];
    char age[3];
};

struct student st;


printf("enter your name: ");
scanf("%s", st.name);
fprintf(ptrShkrues, "%5s", st.name);

printf("enter your age: ");
scanf("%s", st.age);
fprintf(ptrShkrues, "%5s", st.age);
```

So I need to check if its a char or int and display a printf. Is it better to save my age in `INT` is better ? and how to validate it too ?

Comment: The c++ tag is for c++ questions, which this is not.

Comment: Post the definition of `st`.

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:objective-c]?

Comment: Why is `st.name` apparently only 5 characters max, but the input not restricted?

Comment: Aside: it is a good idea to print the results after *all* the inputs have been entered, not after each. Then you can see if one has corrupted another, which would be the case if the user enters a name longer than 14 letters. I suggest you read the man page for `scanf` to see how you restrict string entry length, and what the function's return value means: which is always essential to check. You should also consider what will happen if the name contains a space, for example "Peggy Sue".

Answer (score 0):

Try `fgets` and `sscanf`

```
char buffer[1000];
char name[6];
int age;
fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin); /* needs error checking */
if (sscanf(buffer, "%5s%d", name, &age) != 2) /* error */;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your name and age are char[] type this is how you can check

```
int flag=1;

    for(i=0;i<size&&flag==1;i++){//size is the length of n
        if( isdigit(name[i]) )
            flag=1;
        else
            flag=0;
    }
if(flag==1)
   printf("Is an integer");
else
  printf("It has characters");
```